# Trying to find a dynamic alternative to an if/else statement in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

I am having an issue with the following question: For every hour a cyclist rides his/her bike, they will need to drink 0.5 liters of water. So if a cyclist rides for a total of 1 hour, he/she will need to drink 0.5 liters of water.  If they cycle for 3 hours, it will be a total of 1.5 liters and etc.

My first thought was to use an if/else statement like this:

```
    export function liters(time: number): number {
       if (time === 1){
        return 0.5 liters 
      } else if (time === 1.5) {
         return 1 liters
       }
    }

  const answer = liters(1)
  console.log(answer)
```

But then I realized I can't keep writing if/else statements forever, especially if someone logs 100 hours of cycling. I am sure there is a better way of approaching this problem and making it dynamic.  Does anyone have any recommendations?   I am currently learning TypeScript, so please don't tell me the answer, I would prefer some leads or be pointed in the right direction, that way I can solve by myself. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `time * 0.5`?

Comment: ^ And floor the `time` before that.

Comment: @choz depends on the problem statement. It might also be acceptable not to round - if a cyclist rides for half an hour, they'll still probably need to drink 250ml of water.

Comment: Actually I was supposed to say `ceil` the time. Considering his `else if` statement. But yeah, need more clarification with teh requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to multiple the liters by hour

```
export function liters(time: number): number {
  const litersPerHour = 0.5;
  const total = litersPerHour * time
  return total
}
```